# props data null when component is rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
I have created a generic component to be used in 2 cases. 1 case when dealing with single piece of data the other when dealing with an array of data. I am trying to plot this data on a react leaflet map. Right now it works for my landingPage component which deals with the single plots of data. Previously I had it also working for my array of data before I was passing props to generic component to render. The issue is when I try to load the page responsible for displaying the map with the array of data it returns null when the getInitPosition() function is called as the props data seems to be null when component is rendered but not null after it, I checked this through logging to console. I am confused as to how it works in the single component and not the array of data component as the calls to retrieve the data are very similar. Can anyone see where I am going wrong. It seems to be that although my polyineArray is set with correct values I then print out the polylines state to check if it is set after the call to setPolylines(polylineArray) but it seems to be empty and I do not know why? How can I ensure the polylines state is not empty before passing it as props

**Map array of data component**

```js
import react from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Popup, Polyline } from "react-leaflet";
import axios from "axios";
import polyline from "@mapbox/polyline";
import MapComp from "./MapComp";

function Map() {
  const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
  const [polylines, setPolylines] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setActivitieData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (activities.length) {
      setPolylineArray();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [activities]);

  const getActivityData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8800/api");

    return response.data;
  };

  const setActivitieData = async () => {
    const activityData = await getActivityData();
    setActivities(activityData);
  };

  const setPolylineArray = () => {
    const polylineArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
      const polylineData = activities[i].map.summary_polyline;
      const activityName = activities[i].name;
      const activityType = activities[i].type;

      polylineArray.push({
        positions: polyline.decode(polylineData),
        name: activityName,
        activityType: activityType,
      });
    } // should push activity type as well
    setPolylines(polylineArray);
    //setIsLoading(false);
    console.log("Polyline array = ", polylineArray);
    console.log("polylines = ", polylines);
  };

  return !isLoading ? (
    <MapComp activityData={{ polylines }} />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

**generic map component**

```js
import react from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Popup, Polyline } from "react-leaflet";
import polyline from "@mapbox/polyline";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function MapComp(props) {
  function getInitPosition() {
    console.log("props activity data = ", props);
    if (!Array.isArray(props.activityData)) {
      return [
        props.activityData.positions[0][0],
        props.activityData.positions[0][1],
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        props.activityData.poylines.positions[0][0],
        props.activityData.poylines.positions[0][1],
      ];
    }
  }

  return (
    <MapContainer center={getInitPosition()} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {!Array.isArray(props.activityData) && (
        <Polyline positions={props.activityData.positions}>
          <Popup>
            <div>
              <h2>{"Name: " + +props.activityData.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </Popup>
        </Polyline>
      )}
      {Array.isArray(props.activityData.polylines) &&
        props.activityData.polylines.length > 1 &&
        props.activityData.polylines.map((activity, idx) => (
          <Polyline key={idx} positions={activity.positions}>
            <Popup>
              <div>
                <h2>{"Name: " + activity.name}</h2>
              </div>
            </Popup>
          </Polyline>
        ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default MapComp;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on you common component

```
<MapComp activityData={polylines} />
```

Comment: that did not work as polylines is an array of objects the question states that it is null when rendered not what is passed causing the issue